# Android browser: touchcancel being fired althought touchmove has preventDefault

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webkit, touch

I'm trying to build a Webpage that senses the touch from the user and drags and object along the canvas.

So I'm doing something like this:

```
var touchStart = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do stuff
}
var touchMove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Touch move");
    // Move objs
}
var touchEnd = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Touch start!");
    // clean up stuff
}
var touchCancel = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Oh NO touch cancel!
    console.log("Touch cancel!");

}
bindElemOrig.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
bindElemOrig.addEventListener('touchmove', touchStart, false);
bindElemOrig.addEventListener('touchend', touchStart, false);
bindElemOrig.addEventListener('touchcancel', touchStart, false);
```

It works fine until some point.

The problem is that as soon as I load too many objs, it seems to me that the **touchmove** takes too long to respond, and **touchcancel** gets triggered. The problem is that as soon as **touchcancel** get triggered I don't receive any more **touchmove**s events, and I cannot sense the movement anymore.

Did anyone face this problem? I know about the bug in Android where you must call **preventDefault** ([touchend event in ios webkit not firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691551/touchend-event-in-ios-webkit-not-firing)) but on this case it seems that it is not working because of the memory burden.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on Android 2.3. Android 4+ seems to be ok. Did you find anything on this topic?

Comment: @dioslaska shim @ https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim

Comment: For future reference, the answer here works perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367854/html5-android-touchcancel

Answer (score 3):

like this

```
var touchMove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Touch move");
    // Move objs

    })
}
```

use setTimeout to wrap you logic in touchmove can solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be due to a bug (feature?) in Chrome/Android. See [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260732).

This test demonstrates the behavior ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5wgb/8/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
      var delay = 200;

      var haltEvent = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      };

      var pause = function() {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();

        while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + delay);
      };

      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var target = document.querySelector('#target');
        var status = document.querySelector('#status');

        target.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
          haltEvent(event);
          status.innerHTML = '[touchstart]';
        }, true);

        target.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
          pause();
          haltEvent(event);
          status.innerHTML = '[touchmove]';
        }, true);

        target.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
          status.innerHTML = '[touchend]'; 
        }, true);

        target.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(event) {
          status.innerHTML = '[touchcancel]'; 
        }, true);
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      #target {
        background-color: green;
        height: 300px;
      }

      #status {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="target"></div>
    <p id="status">[]</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't find the touchcancel event to be fired randomly. Instead, it is fired whenever it takes ~200 ms to return from a touchmove event handler.

Answer (score 0):

[Touchcancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchcancel) is specifically designed to take control of touch events and perform regular browser actions such as pan or zoom after a very small touch and move action (nearly 20px, depending on browser).

Your only options are to either:

1. Switch to **Pointer Events** and use the `touch-action` CSS property [as
   explained here](https://github.com/andreszs/jquery.events.swipe#pointer-event-remarks) to
   prevent `pointercancel` from firing (recommended but requires Android 5+)
2. Add `event.preventDefault()` inside your `touchmove` event handler, but this will also disable any default actions like scroll, pan, zoom, etc.

You cannot attemp to cancel or `preventDefault()` inside a `touchcancel` function because it will be too late for that; the browser has already stopped listening to the `touchmove` event. This is by design, not a bug.