# Touchend not firing after touchmove

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, scroll, touch

I'm trying to make a page for mobile devices that detects the `scrollTop` position and scrolls to the top of the page if `scrollTop` is lower than half the document height or scroll to bottom if its not.

I have achieved that by using this:

```
var ScrollTimeout;
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    clearTimeout(ScrollTimeout);
    ScrollTimeout = setTimeout(scrollToTopOrBottom,200);
    });
```

The problem is that the timeout fires when the user has stopped scrolling but still has the finger on the screen.

Then I worked with the `touchend` event and it was great.

```
$(document).on('touchend',function(){
    scrollToTop();
    });
```

The user could stopped scrolling (with the finger still on the screen) and then continue scrolling without triggering the `scrollToTopOrBottom()` function.

The problem is, that event is incosistent between browsers:

In some browsers (Maxthon and Android), the `touchend` event worked as intended but in Opera Mobile and Chrome, the `touchend` event doesn't fires. The explanation for this is that [`touchend` doesn't fires because `touchcancel` has been fired before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691551/touchend-event-in-ios-webkit-not-firing).

I've tried this

```
$(document).on('touchmove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

and succesfully avoided the triggering of `touchcancel`, but unluckily also avoided the natural behaviour of scrolling.

Does anyone know how can this be achieved? I'm completely out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try to attach listener on both touchend and touchcancel.

```
$(document).on('touchend touchcancel', function() {
    doSomthing();
});
```

Comment: tried everything to get touchends to work properly on android 4.4, this was the only thing that helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a shim to deal with this problem Probably a bit late for you but it might help someone.
https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim

Comment: Doesn't work on android 4.4.4 default browser.. doesn't even call the events (ie swipeUp)

Comment: Works, but the swipe events depend on the scrolling of the container. I think manually scrolling is preferable.