# jQuery touchend only fires when touchmove does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I want to execute some code after a `touchmove` has ended. What I can see from using Chrome on Android is that `touchend` only executes if `touchmove` does not?

```
<style>
    div {
        overflow: auto;
        width: 300px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('div').bind('touchstart touchend touchmove', function (e) {
        console.log(e.type);
    });
</script>
```

console doesn't say touchend if touchmove fires.

Comment: Please show an example of your code. SO is not a free coding service (*although it feels like it sometimes*) :)

Comment: Is this related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088117/touchend-not-firing-after-touchmove?rq=1? Take a look at the "Related" section to the right. Seems there are similar issues already being discussed.